# salesforce render inline if tag solution needed

Tags: visualforce, inline

salesforce render inline if tag solution needed.

```
rerender="{!IF(!AND({!isFilterBySelected},!NOT({!isSelectedAll})),'pageBlockID','testCompID')}"
```

getting syntax error...please help

Comment: Can you include the error message in the question please.

Comment: Its not rerender what i expect.   my idea is  , there are two checkbox. when one xCheckbox true and Ycheckbox false then rerender the particular part .        isFilterBySelected and isSelectedAll is checkbox  boolean variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need the `!` after the first curly brace not throughout the string. Also you do not put braces throughout the string. SF is smart enough to merge other variables within the braces.

```
{!IF(AND(isFilterBySelected,NOT(isSelectedAll)))}
```

This will be true if `isFilterBySelected` is **true** AND `isSelectedAll` is **false**